# scope variable ng-bind-html not loading in time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using ng-bind-html to render a string that contains html code.  However, the variable is being pulled from firebase and takes some time to load.  As a result, it is not rendering when the page loads because I suspect the variable doesn't load in time.

The code is straightforward -

```
<br ng-bind-html="invoice.delivery.adr_address">
```

if i instead do this, then I get a line of html code as a string when the variable loads:

```
<br>{{invoice.delivery.adr_address}}
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show more code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that may help. You'll need to use $sce.trustAsHtml to bind it to the dom... And also br is a self closing tag (nothing goes in between), so you'll need to switch that for a div or appropriate tag.

Comment: Thanks! I did not need $sce.trustAsHtml but by changing it to a <span> tag it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned that the page rendering before the data arrives, require the data to load before the template is rendered.  Look at this post regarding using the `resolve` property on the angular route (if using ngRoute).  Tie your Firebase to the incoming property.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using Angular Sanitize.

Comment: I thought sanitize is for modifying the html to remove any unsafe html?  You think that is the problem?